# How to implement refinement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement (so-to-say) a refinement in JavaScript. Kindly look at the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Function Override (Refinement) example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

// original function
function oneFunc() {
    document.writeln("<p> In original oneFunc() </p>");
}

var prevOneFunc = null;
if (oneFunc) {
    prevOneFunc = oneFunc;
}

// redeclared function (should refine/complement the original one)
function oneFunc() { 
    if (prevOneFunc) {
        prevOneFunc(); // should call original oneFunc(), BUT IT ISN'T
    }
    document.writeln("<p> In refined oneFunc() </p>");
}

oneFunc();

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My intention was to have two printouts:

> ```
> In original oneFunc()
> In refined oneFunc()
> ```

However, it seems that since at the *moment of execution* `oneFunc` refers to the new/refined function, hence the output is different than expected. In the debugger checked that I am entering into the infinite recursion :) (yes, understood why exactly).

Please explain which information I am missing to implement it properly.

**Update:** A few limitations: I think (not sure) that I can't modify the original `oneFunc` declaration and it is declared just like described above. I shouldn't modify the declaration of the refined `oneFunc` either.

Comment: Looks like the Decorator pattern (or monkey-patching or duck-punching)

Comment: I would accept one of the answers dealing with "However, it seems that since at the moment of execution oneFunc refers to the new/refined function, hence the output is different than expected." and then create a *new* question. The new question should *show* how the library is being created and how it is accessing said function as this question can't be answered out of that context. (FWIW: Remember that top-level variables/functions are really just properties on the global object.)

Comment: @pst: I hear you and will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of JavaScript hoisting. 
http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Try this:

```
var oneFunc = function(){ 
//In original oneFunc 
};

var prevOneFunc = null;
if (oneFunc) {
    prevOneFunc = oneFunc;
}

oneFunc = function(){
//In refined oneFunc 
};

oneFunc();
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. The problem is that I can't modify the original `oneFunc` function declaration and it is declared just like described above. I shouldn't modify the declaration of the refined `oneFunc` either.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this works or not, but `prevOneFunc = oneFunc()` is not the same as `prevOneFunc = oneFunc`.

Comment: Thanks for linking me up to the article - it provides a perfect explanation on what's happening under the hood. I must admit that in this particular case choosing which answer to mark was a truly challenging mission.

Answer (score 2):

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/gxpK8/

When you do it your way you are defining:

```
prevOneFunc = function oneFunc(){...}
```

So you are not assigning a anonymous function, therefore to do what you want to do you have to declare `oneFunc` like so:

```
oneFunc = function() {
    document.writeln("<p> In original oneFunc() </p>");
}
```

Then later on it is correct:

```
prevOneFunc = function(){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a closure. It avoids (another) global property and shows intent better, at least to me.

```
// original function
function oneFunc() {
   return "world"
}

alert(oneFunc)

oneFunc = (function (original) {
   // a closure will prevent the original function -- which is an object
   // from ever being lost
   return function () { 
      alert("before");
      var ret = original()
      alert("after")
      return "hello " + ret
   }
})(oneFunc)

alert(oneFunc)
```

Happy coding

---

For comment:

The exact same applies. Functions are *just objects*. The only "trick" is making sure someone else calls your object. If the function is a *property* (as in the code shown) then it's easy:

`window.somefunc = myfunc`

`someobj.somefunc = myfunc`

The only case when it's *not easy* (really possible) is when the function has been bound in some for of closure or otherwise accessed via a different mechanism.

Comment: That might work, but I am trying to override/refine some library function, which is called later.

Comment: I have added a little explanation to the bottom of my post. Since the other answers *answer the question*, consider accepting one and creating a *new* question that relates to this other problem. (The problem in the post does not relate. Just updating the post at this time will just lead to much confusion.)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/tylermwashburn/6Fu8Q/

That should do what you want. :)

Comment: That's a marvelously educating example! However, in my case ("refinement") the latter function does not necessarily exist.

Comment: @BreakPhreak If you don't have a second function then what would be "refined" about it?

Comment: I mean that the refinement is optional. The original function might (but not must) be refined.

Comment: @BreakPhreak That'd be the former function. xD I'd try and implement that for you, but it's hard to make the first function optional, when the refiner is a method on top of it.

Comment: Understood. I am sorry for not accepting your answer. As said, it is tremendously educative. At least up-voted (and thankful).